# Why isn’t the phrase “quid nomen tibi es” instead of “quid nomen tibi est”

Tags: grammar-choice

Same with “quid nomen mihi est.” why isn’t it “quid nomen mihi sum”? Does it have to do with mihi and tibi?

Answer (score 8):

The subject of these sentences is *nomen*, so it takes *est*. It's like how we say "my name *is*" and "your name *is*", rather than *"my name *am*" and *"your name *are*".